# Calling d code from an interactive shell

Tags: python, shell, d, pyd

I need an interactive environment where i can call d functions on the fly using a good scripting language with decent scientific plotting libraries (e.g. python).

Is there any way to call d functions from a shell (Ipython or similar)? I looked in to pyd but it seems quite out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wholeheartedly recommend the excellent [LuaD](https://github.com/JakobOvrum/LuaD). It is an **active** project, the author is StackOverflow user and he is also hanging on the official D IRC channel irc://irc.freenode.org/D .

Comment: Thanks for that, it looks really cool. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any documentation for calling d from lua, only the other way around.

Comment: @John_C, you just assign to your lua state, lua["myfun"] = someDG; lua now has a myfun() function it can call.

Comment: so how does this work with the require() function for loading a library? Using the c api i'd have a luaopen_*(lua_State) function containing a lua_register call for each function in the library.

Comment: I believe there is a demo of how to call a D function from your Lua script.

Answer (score 2):

Try [pyd](https://bitbucket.org/ariovistus/pyd) it's a library for writing extensions for python in D, there is even a distutils extension to help building D extensions for use in python.